# Generic type as generic type argument

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

```
// EF (Model) project
class EntityBase { } // base class for all types
class Person : EntityBase // specific implementation for type Person

// ViewModel project
class EditableViewModel<T> where T : EntityBase // base class for all viewmodel types
class PersonViewModel : EditableViewModel<Person>
class CollectionViewModel<T> where T : EditableViewModel<EntityBase> // base class that handles CRUD operation on EditableViewModel<T> collections

// everything up to this point work. I am unable to create specific instance of CollectionViewModel<>
class AllPersonsViewModel : CollectionViewModel<PersonViewModel>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The question is in the last comment, fyi.

Comment: Maybe he didnt have time to read the comment, but did have time to downvote. And then he decided to delete his comment, finding it "ïnappropriate". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do covariance easily enough if you're willing to work with interfaces instead of classes. The following code compiles fine:

```
class EntityBase { }
class Person : EntityBase {}

interface EditableViewModel<out T> where T : EntityBase {} // Must be an interface. "out" marks T as a covariant parameter
class PersonViewModel : EditableViewModel<Person> {}
class CollectionViewModel<T> where T : EditableViewModel<EntityBase> { }

class AllPersonsViewModel : CollectionViewModel<PersonViewModel> { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are deriving from `CollectionViewModel<PersonViewModel>` but you restricted `T` to be a `EditableViewModel<EntityBase>`. `PersonViewModel` is a `EditableViewModel<Person>`, but it is not a `EditableViewModel<EntityBase>`. The two types are unrelated.

Why are they unrelated? Example: If B is assignment-compatible to A, then `List<B>` is not assignment-compatible to `List<A>`.

If you want to know more about this research the topic of co- and contravariance in C#.

Comment: So, that means that I can do covariance on the generic collection type itself, but cannot do it on the type argument? Is there a way around this, so I can achieve above hierarchy?

Comment: Not sure if it is achievable as I don't have experience with this. In any case you need to introduce interfaces because only interfaces can be variant (and delegates). This is going to explode into nastyness, and every dynamic language guy is going to laugh at you: "we don't need such stinkin' type nastyness just to shut up the compiler!" ;-) Maybe this is a hint that you have left the recommended path.

Comment: @usr ... or, you can introduce a second type parameter.  Then you don't need to worry about interfaces (though using interfaces would generally give more flexibility).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this thus:

```
class CollectionViewModel<TEntity, TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : EditableViewModel<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityBase

class AllPersonsViewModel : CollectionViewModel<Person, PersonViewModel>
```

As usr's answer implies, you would get more flexibility if you constrain the types to interfaces rather than abstract base classes; this is especially true if the interface is co- or contravariant.